# AngularStrap with bootstrap-sass-official

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap, bootstrap-sass

Finally getting around to learning front-end development with sass and I'm using bootstrap-sass-official (installed via bower) in an AngularJS project. Id like to try out AngularStrap in this project as well but it's dependency on bootstrap's CSS means I am loading both the standard CSS version as well as the SASS version of bootstrap. Can I use AngularStrap with bootstrap-sass without also requiring the standard CSS?

Comment: Just don't include it in ``index.html``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bower will require the standard bootstrap.css with the installation of angularstrap. Once it is installed, remove the reference to it from your index.html file and you're all set. Thanks to Remco Haszing for the answer!